Sundaram Theorem 8.5
I have one question about this theorem. I do not understand the part after "In particular," in the picture. I assume that ``any monotone transformation'' means that this includes monotonically decreasing transformation. However, if I assume that a transformation is monotonically non-increasing, I am stuck in the proof. (It is obviously true for monotonically non-decreasing transformations.)
By concavity and concavity implies quasi-concavity,
$$f\left(\lambda x + \left(1-\lambda\right)y\right)\geq\lambda f\left(x\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)y\geq \min\{f\left(x\right),f\left(y\right)\}$$
If this is monotonically decreasing,
$$\phi \left(f\left(\lambda x + \left(1-\lambda\right)y\right)\right)\leq\phi \left(\lambda f\left(x\right)+\left(1-\lambda\right)y\right)\leq \phi\left(\min\{f\left(x\right),f\left(y\right)\}\right)$$
However, I do not know how I bring this to
$$\min\{\phi f\left(x\right),\phi f\left(y\right)\}\leq \phi \left(f\left(\lambda x + \left(1-\lambda\right)y\right)\right)$$


Just consider the cases $f(x) \le f(y)$ and $f(x) >f(y)$.

I think the statement is not true. I was just playing around with examples in Desmos, so I by no means guarantee this is the simplest counterexample, but...

Counterexample:
So, we should be able to agree that $f(x) := 1-x^2$ is quasi-concave (and in particular, concave).
Additionally, $\phi(x) := - \sqrt[3]{x}$ is certainly monotone-decreasing on $\mathbb{R}$.

Definitions / Geometric Intuition:
So we ask, is $\phi \circ f$ quasi-concave? If it is, then
$$
(\phi \circ f)(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \ge \min \{ (\phi \circ f)(x), (\phi \circ f)(y) \}
$$
for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ (since the domain of $f$ is the reals).
Geometrically, this means that, if I choose a value $y_0$, then the set
$$
\{ r \in \mathbb{R} \mid (\phi \circ f)(r) \ge y_0 \}
$$
needs to likewise be convex. (This is called an "upper contour set" per Wikipedia's article on quasiconvexity.) Another similarly geometric framing is that, if I build a line with endpoints
$$
(x,M), (y,M) \text{ where } M:= \min \{ (\phi \circ f)(x), (\phi \circ f)(y) \}
$$
and look at the entire area above that line, the graph should of the function should never poke below that line between that given $x$ and $y$. (Otherwise an intermediate point actually gives the graph a lower minimum.)

Counterexample Continued:
(Desmos demo here.)
So, pulling back to my counterexample, just graph things for $x \in [-2,2]$. Then your picture is something like this:

The graph breaks through! The composition is not quasiconcave!
To see what some quasiconcave functions would look like, here are some examples:
$g(x) := -x^2$:

$g(x) := -\sqrt{|x|}$:

$g(x) := \sqrt[3]{x}$:


Conclusion:
Hence, I think the text means to only include nondecreasing functions $\phi$.
This seems corroborated by a result here which requires the outer function be increasing and the inner quasiconcave.
